# How to apply a excel formula to millions of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that basically compares between each columns of two different sheets and outputs the different on another sheet

Something like : 
=IF(Jan!A1<>Feb!A1,"JanSales: "&Jan!A1&char(10)&"FebSales: "&Feb!A1,"")

Basically this gives the exact differences between the Jan and Feb data which I can drag the formula cell to give me results for the desired number of rows. However the problem is I have nearly 0.5 million rows in the sheet. Is there a better way other than dragging the cursor till 0.5 Million rows

Thanks

Comment: You can double-click the drag handle to have it fill the rest of the rows

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Tried that already

Comment: Copy the cell (CTRL+C) then use GoTo (Ctrl+G) followed by SelectUp (CTRL+SHIFT+UP), Then use Paste (CTRL+V)

Comment: Is the formula adjacent to the data?

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent

Comment: @Luuk: To a certain extent this helped

Comment: @this-me :  To which etend did it not help?

Comment: I will accept your comment as answer if you post it as Answer